# Какие существуют аналоги библиотеки curl для С++?

Tags: visual-c++, curl

Мне всего-то нужно скачать 1 файл, но ссылка с https. Написал скачивание с использованием curl, в итоге исполняемый файл стал на много больше занимать +теперь никак не получается MSCVRT как static-библиотеку подключить ибо конфликтирует с libcurl почему-то. Есть ли какие-то аналоги библиотеки curl? Или может быть есть какие-то другие способы скачать файл по ссылке с https? Проект на Visual C++ 2017.

Comment: Странно, у меня curl в таком варианте вполне нормально линковалась - если ее собирать как статическую...

Comment: Harry та curl то нормально прилинковался, но когда захотел прилинковать статически библиотеку MSVCRT вылетела ошибка: "LNK4098 библиотека по умолчанию "MSVCRT" противоречит использованию других библиотек; используйте параметр /NODEFAULTLIB:library" и внизу ещё куча ошибок связанных с libcurl.

Comment: А компилировали как `/MT`?

Comment: Harry ну так да, был /MD , а как пришлось собрать с /MT - обломался. Сейчас нашёл инфу о WinInet, там тоже можно с SSL работать. Не знаю зачем я вообще с этим curl под Windows связался)) он походу только под linux норм